# $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$; $a+b+c+d=0,M=ab+bc+cd,N=ac+ad+bd$; prove that at least one of $20M+17N$ and $20N+17M$ is non-positive

Tags: real-numbers

> $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers summing to zero. Let $M=ab+bc+cd$ and $N=ac+ad+bd$. Prove that at least one of the sums $20M+17N$ and $20N+17M$ is non-positive.

Comment: Where did you come across this question, please?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I don't know  my teacher gives to us

Comment: I try to simplfy but i can't

Comment: Looks like it is worth starting with the fact that $(a+b+c+d)^2=0$ ...

Comment: Your teacher in what class, please? Is it homework? Is it an exam?

Comment: differential equation ,not homework but likely that

Comment: I'd really like to see how a question like this could come up in the study of differential equations! It would make your question so much more interesting, if you could include that.

Answer (score 2):

You have that $ (a+b+c+d)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}+2(M+N) $ so since $ a+b+c+d=0 $, you get that $ 2(M+N)=-(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}) \leq 0 $.

Now let $ S_{1}=20M+17N $ and $ S_{2}=20N+17M $. Then $ S_{1}+S_{2}=37(M+N) \leq 0 $ by the above so at least one of them must be non-positive, otherwise their sum would be greater than $ 0 $ , which is clearly absurd by the above.

Comment: you're welcome!